# "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required 'java.util.List'." Or how to convert Python list to Java.util list?

Tags: python, java, rest

This one has the better  of me, for sure.

I am attempting to use the [USDA FoodData Central](https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/fdc-app.html#/) Rest API for Python, and I have extensively reviewed the related documentation, online materials and SwaggerHub simulations.

**To make a long story short, it seems I need to convert a Python list to a 'java.util.List', something not in [the USDA documentation](https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/api-guide.html), and something I have not been able to make happen. Despite my efforts, I am unable to even *attempt* to make that conversion happen, because I cannot install the Python dependencies**.
It boils down to two questions overall:

1. How do I convert a Python list to a Java.Util.List if possible?
2. What can I do about the problems installing the dependencies (e.g. jep) when it appears they are deprecated?

The USDA site sends you to a SwaggerHub simulation. It was helpful, and it gave me the URL pasted below as a model for my API. However, the instructions regarding the *required* 'fdcIds list' says nothing at all about the need to convert to Java.

**To be clear, the 'fdcIds list' is simply the desired Python list of the six-digit numbers that represent all the food items and products in the USDA database. You can request up to 20 at a time and the API returns a complete nutritional profile of each.
You will see what I mean if you follow the SwaggerHub link below**

Here is the Swaggerhub model URL with the link below:

```
https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods?fdcIds=173567&fdcIds=173565&fdcIds=173571&format=abridged&nutrients=208&nutrients=204&nutrients=205&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/fdcnal/food-data_central_api/1.0.0#/info
```

Here are SwaggerHub instructions for the fdcID list pasted in their entirety:

```
"fdcIds (reguired)
array[string]
(query)
List of multiple FDC ID's. Should be comma separated list (e.g. fdcIds=534358,373052) or repeating parameters (e.g. fdcIds=534358&fdcIds=373052)."
```

I think the rest of my code (below) is fine, because otherwise the SwaggerHub simulation produces the desired results.

Here is the complete error message I received afterwards:

---

```
'error': 'Bad Request',
 'message': "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required "
            "type 'java.util.List'; nested exception is "
            'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: '
            '"[{\'fdcids\':173567},{\'fdcids\':173565},{\'fdcids\':173571},{\'fdcids\':173569},{\'fdcids\':173564}]"',
 'path': '/portal-data/api/v1/foods',
 'status': 400,
 'timestamp': '2022-04-15T21:49:49.609+0000'}
```

---

I know Python and JavaScript. I know nothing about Java.

However, I attempted to install the Python packages necessary for this operation, such as [jdk](https://pypi.org/project/install-jdk/) and [jep](https://pypi.org/project/jep/), but I ran into additional error messages, as it seems the packages are deprecated(?)  - though I am not sure. I forced the jep installation, but it still did not install successfully.

The error messages related to the failed installations are too long to paste here; but I will provide examples that seem to represent the gist of the problem.

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
error: metadata-generation-failed
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have spent the past several trying to make this API work. I've been working on the related app for almost a year. I will send a request for technical assistance to the USDA, but I could use some help if anyone has some genuine insights or has resolved similar issues.

The USDA API is a popular one. It apparently works for most developers. I am hoping someone can help. I am a bit mystified by these obstacles.

My operating system is Windows 10 64 bit.

My code, as it stands, is pasted below.

I should note the variables in the URL were originally in a "parameters" dictionary.
But then, I started to receive error messages stating the dictionary did not contain the fields in the requested URL, which was not true. It seemed to work better when I made them standalone variables...except for the conversion issues related to the fdcIds list.

At that point, I started to receive error messages like the one in the title related to my failure to convert the Python list to a Java Util.List. I have reviewed all the online information and videos I could find about Python rest apis and possible solutions to the Java conversion problem, including all related questions on Stackoverflow.

I am at a loss as to how I should proceed.

Your sincere feedback is much appreciated.

Thank you for reviewing my question.

Below, I pasted my code in its entirety. Again, I have also tried to place the variables in the URL inside a parameters dictionary. But it only caused more trouble.

```
import requests
import pprint

api_key = 'AcAm9H2jcFikw4f5PmJl0hFJSjreMwg9BN621tQD'               
pagesize = 5,
fdcIds = [{'fdcids': 173567}, {'fdcids': 173565}, {'fdcids': 173571}, {'fdcids': 173569}, {'fdcids': 173564}]
format = 'abridged'
dataType = 'SR Legacy'
foodNutrients = [208, 204,205]

url = f"https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods?fdcIds={fdcIds}&format={format}&dataType={dataType}&nutrients={foodNutrients}&pagesize={pagesize}'&api_key={api_key}"

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'}

data = requests.get(url, headers).json()
print(requests.status_codes)
pprint.pprint(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `fdcIds` as shown below and also `foodNutrients`:

```
import requests
import pprint

api_key = 'AcAm9H2jcFikw4f5PmJl0hFJSjreMwg9BN621tQD'          
pagesize = 5
# fdcIds = [{'fdcids': 173567}, {'fdcids': 173565}, {'fdcids': 173571}, {'fdcids': 173569}, {'fdcids': 173564}]
fdcIds = "173567,173565,173571,173569,173564"
f = 'abridged'
dataType = 'SR Legacy'
foodNutrients = "208, 204, 205"

url = f"https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods?fdcIds={fdcIds}&format={f}&dataType={dataType}&nutrients={foodNutrients}&pagesize={pagesize}'&api_key={api_key}"
print(url)
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'}

data = requests.get(url, headers).json()
print(requests.status_codes)
pprint.pprint(data)
```

Result:

```
[{'dataType': 'SR Legacy',
  'description': 'Shortening frying (heavy duty), beef tallow and cottonseed',
  'fdcId': 173567,
  'foodNutrients': [{'amount': 100,
                     'name': 'Total lipid (fat)',
                     'number': '204',
                     'unitName': 'G'},
                    {'amount': 0.0,
                     'name': 'Carbohydrate, by difference',
                     'number': '205',
                     'unitName': 'G'},
                    {'amount': 900,
                     'derivationCode': 'NC',
                     'derivationDescription': 'Calculated',
                     'name': 'Energy',
                     'number': '208',
                     'unitName': 'KCAL'}],
  'ndbNumber': '4550',
  'publicationDate': '2019-04-01'},
 {'dataType': 'SR Legacy',
  'description': 'Fat, chicken',
  'fdcId': 173564,
  'foodNutrients': [{'amount': 900,
                     'derivationCode': 'NC',
                     'derivationDescription': 'Calculated',
                     'name': 'Energy',
                     'number': '208',
                     'unitName': 'KCAL'},
                    {'amount': 99.8,
                     'name': 'Total lipid (fat)',
                     'number': '204',
                     'unitName': 'G'},
                    {'amount': 0.0,
                     'name': 'Carbohydrate, by difference',
                     'number': '205',
                     'unitName': 'G'}],
  'ndbNumber': '4542',
  'publicationDate': '2019-04-01'},
 {'dataType': 'SR Legacy',
  'description': 'Fat, turkey',
  'fdcId': 173571,
  'foodNutrients': [{'amount': 99.8,
                     'name': 'Total lipid (fat)',
                     'number': '204',
                     'unitName': 'G'},
                    {'amount': 0.0,
                     'name': 'Carbohydrate, by difference',
                     'number': '205',
                     'unitName': 'G'},
                    {'amount': 900,
                     'derivationCode': 'NC',
                     'derivationDescription': 'Calculated',
                     'name': 'Energy',
                     'number': '208',
                     'unitName': 'KCAL'}],
  'ndbNumber': '4575',
  'publicationDate': '2019-04-01'},
 {'dataType': 'SR Legacy',
  'description': 'Oil, soybean, salad or cooking, (partially hydrogenated) and '
                 'cottonseed',
  'fdcId': 173565,
  'foodNutrients': [{'amount': 100,
                     'name': 'Total lipid (fat)',
                     'number': '204',
                     'unitName': 'G'},
                    {'amount': 0.0,
                     'name': 'Carbohydrate, by difference',
                     'number': '205',
                     'unitName': 'G'},
                    {'amount': 884,
                     'derivationCode': 'NC',
                     'derivationDescription': 'Calculated',
                     'name': 'Energy',
                     'number': '208',
                     'unitName': 'KCAL'}],
  'ndbNumber': '4543',
  'publicationDate': '2019-04-01'},
 {'dataType': 'SR Legacy',
  'description': 'Shortening industrial, soybean (hydrogenated) and cottonseed',
  'fdcId': 173569,
  'foodNutrients': [{'amount': 0.0,
                     'name': 'Carbohydrate, by difference',
                     'number': '205',
                     'unitName': 'G'},
                    {'amount': 884,
                     'derivationCode': 'NC',
                     'derivationDescription': 'Calculated',
                     'name': 'Energy',
                     'number': '208',
                     'unitName': 'KCAL'},
                    {'amount': 100,
                     'derivationCode': 'A',
                     'derivationDescription': 'Analytical',
                     'name': 'Total lipid (fat)',
                     'number': '204',
                     'unitName': 'G'}],
  'ndbNumber': '4554',
  'publicationDate': '2019-04-01'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in which you can pass the fdcIds:

`Should be comma separated list (e.g. fdcIds=534358,373052) or repeating parameters (e.g. fdcIds=534358&fdcIds=373052).`

This is mentioned [here](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/fdcnal/food-data_central_api/1.0.0#/FDC/getFoods). Try to pass the ids in these formats.